# Extend an array in a loop python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to extend a numpy array in a loop. Any ideas how?

```
dataA = np.array([])
for i in range(30):
    data1 = np.random.rand(100,3)
    dataA = np.append(dataA,data1,axis=0)
```

Edit: Thanks for your comments. Below code works.

```
dataA = np.empty([0,3])
for i in range(30):
    data1 = np.random.rand(100,3)
    dataA = np.vstack([dataA,data1])
```

Comment: initialize as `dataA = np.ndarray((0,3))`?

Comment: how about `np.vstack([np.random.rand(100,3) for _ in range(30)])`

Comment: Set `dataA = np.empty([0,3])`

Comment: What was the problem?  What do you want, in the end?  A (30,100,3) random array?  or (3000,3)?  Why do this in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The above code doesn't work because the array dataA has dimension (0,) , whereas the data1 array has a dimension (100,3). You can do a couple of things:
1. create an empty np array of dimension (100,3) by using numpy.empty or numpy.zeros.
2.

```
dataA = np.random.rand(100,3)
for i in range(29):
    data1 = np.random.rand(100,3)
    dataA = np.append(dataA, data1 ,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you MUST iterate, use a list:

```
In [302]: alist = []                                                                                         
In [303]: for _ in range(4): 
     ...:     alist.append(np.random.rand(2,5)) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [304]: alist                                                                                              
Out[304]: 
[array([[0.09210494, 0.43370117, 0.43086276, 0.4936851 , 0.42583029],
        [0.31226122, 0.42635131, 0.89338916, 0.94416002, 0.50183668]]),
 array([[0.62395295, 0.1156184 , 0.31728548, 0.41482621, 0.86630916],
        [0.25045537, 0.48303426, 0.98555979, 0.51948512, 0.61289453]]),
 array([[0.12062867, 0.8263408 , 0.60306013, 0.54506801, 0.34276383],
        [0.30412079, 0.41702221, 0.68130077, 0.87545684, 0.51042234]]),
 array([[0.66931378, 0.58593655, 0.6249035 , 0.67468905, 0.84234244],
        [0.08319499, 0.76368284, 0.24366637, 0.19422296, 0.57245696]])]
In [305]: np.array(alist).shape                                                                              
Out[305]: (4, 2, 5)
In [306]: np.array(alist)                                                                                    
Out[306]: 
array([[[0.09210494, 0.43370117, 0.43086276, 0.4936851 , 0.42583029],
        [0.31226122, 0.42635131, 0.89338916, 0.94416002, 0.50183668]],

       [[0.62395295, 0.1156184 , 0.31728548, 0.41482621, 0.86630916],
        [0.25045537, 0.48303426, 0.98555979, 0.51948512, 0.61289453]],

       [[0.12062867, 0.8263408 , 0.60306013, 0.54506801, 0.34276383],
        [0.30412079, 0.41702221, 0.68130077, 0.87545684, 0.51042234]],

       [[0.66931378, 0.58593655, 0.6249035 , 0.67468905, 0.84234244],
        [0.08319499, 0.76368284, 0.24366637, 0.19422296, 0.57245696]]])

In [314]: np.vstack(alist)                                                                                   
Out[314]: 
array([[0.09210494, 0.43370117, 0.43086276, 0.4936851 , 0.42583029],
       [0.31226122, 0.42635131, 0.89338916, 0.94416002, 0.50183668],
       [0.62395295, 0.1156184 , 0.31728548, 0.41482621, 0.86630916],
       [0.25045537, 0.48303426, 0.98555979, 0.51948512, 0.61289453],
       [0.12062867, 0.8263408 , 0.60306013, 0.54506801, 0.34276383],
       [0.30412079, 0.41702221, 0.68130077, 0.87545684, 0.51042234],
       [0.66931378, 0.58593655, 0.6249035 , 0.67468905, 0.84234244],
       [0.08319499, 0.76368284, 0.24366637, 0.19422296, 0.57245696]])
```

You can use some version of `concatenate` in a loop (`append`, `vstack`), but it will be slower, and is harder to start.

If possible try to make the array without a loop, for example with `np.random.rand(2,3,4)` or `np.random.rand(20,4)`.